# Rotate a bitmap inside a layer-list

Tags: java, android, xml, bitmap, layer

I'm trying to rotate a `bitmap` which is contained in an `item` inside a `layer-list`. The `layer-list` is defined in an Android XML file. I would like to adjust the rotation of the `bitmap` from inside an Android activity. I understand that bitmaps can be rotated using a `Matrix` however I'm not sure how to update the bitmap contained inside the XML file.

My code so far is:

```
// Inside Activity
Bitmap bitmapOrg = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                R.drawable.face_line_green);

        int width = bitmapOrg.getWidth();
        int height = bitmapOrg.getHeight();

        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.postRotate(10);

        Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmapOrg, 0, 0,
                width, height, matrix, true);

// Inside XML
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item android:top="6px">
            <bitmap android:src="@drawable/face_line_red" android:gravity="center" android:id="@+id/line_red" />
        </item>
        <item android:left="4px">
            <bitmap android:src="@drawable/face_line_green"
                android:gravity="center" android:id="@+id/line_green" />
        </item>
    </layer-list>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily rotate `Bitmap` using a `RotateDrawable`. As a result, the easiest way to perform a `Bitmap` rotation is to wrap it in a `RotateDrawable` which will also be wrapped in your `LayerListDrawable`.

Comment: Thanks for the help but I'm still a little stuck. So I setup the XML like this: `<item android:left="4px">
  <rotate android:id="@+id/line_green"><bitmap android:src="@drawable/face_line_green"
   android:gravity="center" /></rotate>
 </item>`?
How do I then change the rotation using `RotateDrawable` in the main Activity?

Comment: You need to change the current level (via `setLevel`) of your `Drawable`